# Is this path necessarily surjective?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

Let $V$ be an simply connected bounded open subset of $\mathbb{C}$ and $\alpha\colon[0,1]\rightarrow \partial V$ be a loop. If there exists $z\in V$ such that $\operatorname{Wnd}(\alpha,z)=1$, then is it true that $\partial V= \alpha([0,1])$?

I think the answer is yes, but I have trouble proving this. How do I prove this?

Comment: THis might depend on your definition of "loop": continuous, simple, rectifiable...or what?

Comment: I think it does not matter. However, if it depends, let's assume a loop to be a closed rectifiable curve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.

Let $V=\Bbb D\setminus [0,1]$. and $\alpha(t)=e^{2\pi i t}$

Comment: @Rubertos But I have to admit that I wanted to start writing a positive proof :)

Comment: I will post a question which is my original problem. I think it is true in this case.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1968202/44669